# Issues with intern-runner and proxyUrl that contains subfolders

Tags: testing, proxy, intern

I need to setup intern to test ajax calls from a different server. I set everything up sort of following the official wiki in this address
https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Using-Intern-to-unit-test-Ajax-calls

My config file has proxyUrl set to `http://localhost:8080/sub`
and `http://localhost:8080/sub` is setup as a reverse proxy to inter-runner in `http://localhost:9000`

When I run `./node_modules/.bin/intern-runner -config=tests/config` from the tests root folder, the browser opens up and is able to request several files, until it tries to request the config file. That's when it receives a 404, because it requests the wrong address - `http://localhost:8080/tests/config.js` - without the sub folder.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something inside the config file, or if intern is not able to use proxies with subfolders. I tried to set the baseUrl parameter, but it had no effect.

Any ideas?

### Update:

It seems that sometimes intern-runner uses the path provided in the config param, and sometimes it uses the one in the proxyUrl parameter inside the config file. As a workaround, what I did was to place the config file and the tests on 2 folders (actually I made a symbolic link). The first on `tests/` and the second on `sub/tests/` and ran it using `./node_modules/.bin/intern-runner -config=sub/tests/config`.

It works, but it's kind of stupid and I really wished there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a limitation/bug of intern. It assumes that the proxy sits at the root of the absolute domain name, i.e. that it has a pathname of `/`.

An issue has been created on intern's github repository [here](https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/250) and the corresponding pull request that fixes the problem is [here](https://github.com/theintern/intern/pull/251). Hopefully this gets merged into the upcoming 2.1 release of intern.